# How to export environment variables during R package installation?

Tags: r, installation, package, environment-variables

I have an `R` package which depends on a third party library. I need to export an environment variable ( a path) in order to be able to use the package. I do not want to do this manually and want to provide the value for the environment variable as an argument during the package installation and then set the environment variable for my system. Is it possible by using a configure.ac script (using autotools)? I can get the value of the arguments provided during the installation in my configure.ac but I am not able to set the value of environment variable. How should I set the environment variable here? I am open to other approaches too.

Comment: Probably the big difficulty is that doing it during package *installation* won't help.  The user could change things subsequently.  You need to do this when `source` or `library` call loads the library.  And **that** means that anyone who just wants to import a function from your library's NameSpace might be outta luck. How about embedding the 3rd party library **inside** your package, so it's on the package path?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, so the variable must be exported every time during the load(package_name). I will see if I can embed the library in my package. But for a temporary solution setting the variable during installation would help as practically it is highly improbable that the user would change something in this case.